# Render another new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two routes with new action for the same resource: `individual_trainings` :

```
new_backend_trainer_ind_training GET    /backend/people/:id/trainers/:trainer_id/individual_trainings/new(.:format)         backend/individual_trainings#new

new_backend_individual_training  GET    /backend/individual_trainings/new(.:format)                                         backend/individual_trainings#new
```

How to specify what type of `new` should be rendered? If I use `render :new`, always redirect to second route. I don't want to use `redirect_to`, because I cannot handle errors for form. Any idea how to do this (I need `render :new` in create action). Maybe another new and create action?

Update:
I think there is a problem with simple_form in `new_backend_trainer_ind_training` :

```
= simple_form_for([:backend, @individual_training]) do |f|
```

it generates wrong url. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it this way (two routes for the same action) then you can pass path to simple_form:

```
= simple_form_for(@individual_training, url: new_backend_trainer_ind_training_path) do |f|
```

However, this is a bad approach to use different routes leading to the same action. If this is a different behavior, then you should create another controller with it's `new/create` action.